# Connecting to database in Vagrant via Django

Tags: mysql, django, vagrant

I have a Django project set up that I want to run in a Vagrant vm. I was able to get the vm up and provisioned, and I have a MySQL database set up inside the vm that I'd like the Django app to connect to, but every time I attempt to run runserver I get this error:

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")`

Which seems like it's still trying to connect to my local MySQL instance.

My Vagrant networks settings are as follows:

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.3"
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3306, host: 8000
```

And the Django database settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'PORT': 8000
    }
}
```

Tried the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810475/how-to-connect-to-a-database-inside-vagrant) without success.

Comment: What happens if you connect to mysql from your host with some tool like MySQLBench? Can you connect to mysql inside your vm manually? Do you get any vagrant errors that maybe the host port is already in use?

Answer (score 1):

I was also having this issue. I have fixed this by editing `settings.py`
provide the name hostname in the parameters of `DATABASE`.
Finally the `DATABASE` parameters will be as below

`DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'djangodb',
        'USER':'root',
        'PASSWORD':'root',
        'HOST':'127.0.0.1'
    }
}`

It worked for me.